# Activate kubernetes logs only for selected pods

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd, fluent-bit

I would like to annotate some kubernetes pods with an annotation like `please_log_with_parser: myparser` and have something like `fluentbit` to *only* process the logs of those pods with the given parser to our elastic search cluster.

For fluentbit I'm only aware of annotation `fluentbit.io/exclude`, but that would result in having to annotate all other pods. - Is is possible to tell fluentbit to *only* process logs having a label, or otherwise discarding all messages without the proper annotation?

Is there maybe an alternative to fluentbit, which is able to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude namespace from fluent-bit logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027935/how-to-exclude-namespace-from-fluent-bit-logging)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu No. That one is about *excluding* *everything* in some namespace. Mine is about *including* *only* annotated pods.

Answer (score 3):

One option is using a combination of `kubernetes`, `nest`, and `grep` filter like in [this example](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.3/filter/grep#nested-fields-example).

You use the `kubernetes` filter to create metadata like this:

```
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "myapp-0",
        "namespace_name": "default",
        "pod_id": "216cd7ae-1c7e-11e8-bb40-000c298df552",
        "annotations": {
            "please_log_with_parser": "myparser"
        },
        "host": "minikube",
        "container_name": "myapp",
        "docker_id": "370face382c7603fdd309d8c6aaaf434fd98b92421ce7c7c8aafe7697d4aa362"
    }
}
```

Then use `nest` to lift the annotation to the top level.
Then use `grep` to discard only keep the record if that annotation is present.

My helm values now look like this:

```
rawConfig: |-
 @INCLUDE fluent-bit-service.conf
 @INCLUDE fluent-bit-input.conf
 @INCLUDE fluent-bit-filter.conf
 [FILTER]
     Name         nest
     Match        *
     Operation    lift
     Nested_under kubernetes
     Add_prefix   kubernetes_
 [FILTER]
     Name         nest
     Match        *
     Operation    lift
     Nested_under kubernetes_annotations
     Add_prefix   kubernetes_annotations_
 [FILTER]
     Name    grep
     Match   *
     Regex   kubernetes_annotations_fluentbit.io/parser .*
 [FILTER]
     Name         nest
     Match        *
     Operation    nest
     Wildcard     kubernetes_annotations_*
     Nest_under   kubernetes_annotations
     Remove_prefix   kubernetes_annotations_
 [FILTER]
     Name         nest
     Match        *
     Operation    nest
     Wildcard     kubernetes_*
     Nest_under   kubernetes
     Remove_prefix  kubernetes_
 @INCLUDE fluent-bit-output.conf
```